# How to get all items in column db_select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, drupal

I have a table `voting_nomination_counter` in which 4 columns. I need to get all the values ​​of the column `uid`. I'm trying to make it so:

```
$sql = db_select('voting_nomination_counter', 'v')
    ->fields('v', array('uid'))
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAssoc();

$user_id = array();
foreach ($sql as $item) {
    $user_id[] = $item;
}
```

But returns only one value. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = db_select('voting_nomination_counter', 'v')
->fields('v', array('uid'))
->execute()
->fetchAssoc();
```

Remove fetchAssoc() and write it as:

```
$sql = db_select('voting_nomination_counter', 'v')
->fields('v', array('uid'))
->execute();
```

or

```
$sql = db_select('voting_nomination_counter', 'v')
->fields('v', array('uid'))
->execute()
->fetchAll();
```